# How to tell if I am correctly fitting a normal distribution to data using Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, pca, normal-distribution

I have a data set with about 10 continuous features and 1000 binary (categorical) features. After scaling and normalizing the data so that every feature has a mean of 0.0, I perform PCA on the data to get a reduced matrix `z`, keeping about 90% of the variance (keeping ~700 principal components).

If I now want to fit a normal distribution to the data I have the code below

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
mean = np.mean(z, axis=0)
cov = np.cov(z, rowvar=0)

g = multivariate_normal(mean=mean, cov=cov)

# put a random sample of z through the pdf
# to check the probability of the sample occurring
print(g.pdf(z[np.random.randint(z.shape[0]),:]))
>>> 0.0
```

The problem is, no matter how many times I run `print(g.pdf(z[np.random.randint(z.shape[0]),:]))`, I get an output of 0.0. I appreciate some samples in `z` will lie further from the mean than average, giving me and answer of close to 0.0. But I would have thought that at least some samples in `z` would be closer to the mean and therefore give me a much larger answer when I put a random value `z` through the pdf.

This may be something to do with my original data, or the reduced dataset `z` and how these are distributed. But I have performed multiple checks on both the original data set and `z` to ensure there are no `nan` values, ensuring the mean of each column of `z` is in fact 0.0 etc.

My results indicate that I have gaussian with extremely thin tails (a very narrow gaussian) so that everything is far from the peak. I don't think this should be the case.

Am I using `multivariate_normal` correctly? Are there any other checks I could perform on the data or otherwise? I know I am making a big assumption that the data is normally distributed, but surely not all values in `z` should yield a pdf value of 0.0.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and run (with no further editing required) to demonstrate the problem.  That might require including a small dataset in the question, or writing some code that generates a random dataset that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Too many words KillerT. Cut down the length to one paragraph tops. Your issue is two fold: 1. Are you using he functions correctly. 2. Is your model assumption a good one. It looks like you’re using the functions fine. Maybe print out the top few max/min values of the covariance and mean? You can have really sharp curvature in high dim space. Why not iterate the entire z-vector and see if they are all 0.0?